# VUE JS Consumindo API e usando V-FOR com 2 tabelas

Tags: vue.js

Tenho 2 tabelas

Tabela 1

```
[
{"Id": "1", "nome": "João"},
{"Id": "2", "nome": "Manoel"}
]
```

Tabela 2

```
[
{"Estudante": "1", "nota": "5", "avaliação": "1"},
{"Estudante": "1", "nota": "6", "avaliação": "2"},
{"Estudante": "1", "nota": "7", "avaliação": "3"},
{"Estudante": "1", "nota": "8", "avaliação": "4"},
{"Estudante": "2", "nota": "3", "avaliação": "1"},
{"Estudante": "2", "nota": "5", "avaliação": "2"},
{"Estudante": "2", "nota": "8", "avaliação": "3"},
{"Estudante": "2", "nota": "9", "avaliação": "4"}
]
```

Preciso renderizar da seguinte forma

```
 Estudante: Jose
 Evaluation 1 | nota 5
 Evaluation 2 | nota 6
 Evaluation 3 | nota 7
 Evaluation 4 | nota 8

 Estudante: Mark
 Evaluation 1 | nota 3
 Evaluation 2 | nota 5
 Evaluation 3 | nota 8
 Evaluation 4 | nota 9
```

Estou usando o v-resource chamando os dados por PHP da Tabela 1 que é a lista de estudantes e usando o V-FOR  para exibir

```
 <Div v-for="Estudante in Estudantes">
 Estudante {{Estudante.nome}}
 </Div>
```

Agora precisaria dentro deste primeiro V-FOR, invocar um outro $HTTP.POST passando o ID para a query me trazer apenas os dados relacionados ao determinado aluno dentro do laço.

Qual a melhor forma de executar esse sistema?

Answer (score 2):

Tens de criar um valor dinamico, [com *computed*](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html), e aí podes criar um script que faz merge desses dados assim:

```
  computed: {
    Alunos: function() {
      var notas = this.Notas;
      return this.Estudantes.map(function(estudante) {
        estudante.notas = [];
        notas.forEach(function(entrada) {
          if (entrada.Estudante == estudante.Id) estudante.notas.push(entrada)
        });
        return estudante;
      });
   }
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var nomes = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "nome": "João"
}, {
  "Id": "2",
  "nome": "Manoel"
}];

var notas = [{
  "Estudante": "1",
  "nota": "5",
  "avaliação": "1"
}, {
  "Estudante": "1",
  "nota": "6",
  "avaliação": "2"
}, {
  "Estudante": "1",
  "nota": "7",
  "avaliação": "3"
}, {
  "Estudante": "1",
  "nota": "8",
  "avaliação": "4"
}, {
  "Estudante": "2",
  "nota": "3",
  "avaliação": "1"
}, {
  "Estudante": "2",
  "nota": "5",
  "avaliação": "2"
}, {
  "Estudante": "2",
  "nota": "8",
  "avaliação": "3"
}, {
  "Estudante": "2",
  "nota": "9",
  "avaliação": "4"
}];
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    Estudantes: nomes,
    Notas: notas
  },
  computed: {
    Alunos: function() {
      var notas = this.Notas;
      return this.Estudantes.map(function(estudante) {
        estudante.notas = [];
        notas.forEach(function(entrada) {
          if (entrada.Estudante == estudante.Id) estudante.notas.push(entrada)
        });
        return estudante;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.7/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="Estudante in Alunos">
      Estudante: {{ Estudante.nome }}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="notas in Estudante.notas">
          Evaluation {{notas['avaliação']}} | nota {{notas.nota}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Imagina um universo de 10 mil alunos, não posso trazer todos esses dados de uma só vez,  por isso preciso chamar por ajax dentro de uma paginação.  Exemplo vou mostrar apenas os 10 primeiros alunos,  e preciso trazer do banco de dados por PHP apenas as notas dos 10 primeiros alunos,  por isso eu precisaria consultar por POST o banco de dados passando o ID de cada aluno exibido separadamente.

Comment: @NixonGirard sempre que mudares o valor do `data` do Vue ele vai correr o `computed` novamente.